# How to avoid re-running useEffect with API call while using react-hot-loader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I'm using `react-hot-loader` in my local environment to develop my React + Firebase app.

For a basic component without API calls, I can see changes immediately (it only updates the changed part). But when I'm styling a component that has an API call inside a `useEffect` like the following example, it keeps re-running everything (including the effect) and I lose my current state.

The logs after I change something:

[image]

I'm not sure if the issue is because of the `useEffect` or the API call.

**QUESTION**

How can I fix this? Like, if I change the CSS color for a tag, I would like all my state to remain unchanged and update only the changed part.

Example:

**ComponentWithApiCall.js**

```
function ComponentWithAPICall() {

  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataFromAPI,setDataFromAPI] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{

    // CALL API WAIT FOR RESULTS
    setDataFromAPI(result);
    setLoading(false);

  },[]);

  return(
    dataFromAPI &&
      <div>
        // WHATEVER
      </div>
  );
}
```

Here's my current configs for the `react-hot-loader`. I'm also using `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server`.

**webpack.dev.js**

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },

  plugins:[
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin()
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  }
```

**App.js**

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';

// App component

export default hot(withRouter(App));    // I'M ALSO USING react-router
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?